# word that means "that which is being predicted"

Tags: single-word-requests

If we are using one thing to predict another, the first thing might be called a "signal" or more generically a "predictor". What might we call the thing being predicted?

For example, if the weather in Iowa is being used to predict corn prices six months later, today's weather in Iowa is a "signal" or "predictor." How might one refer to the price of corn six months hence?

"Target" doesn't seem right. "Predictee" seems cloying (and is in any case not a real word). "Prediction" is wrong, as it refers to expected outcomes rather than reality, and would lead to sentences like "We used the data to generate a prediction of the prediction."

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your ***prediction***, brother.

Comment: @DanBron 'Prediction' refers to what you think is going to happen. I'm looking for the word that describes the *thing you are trying to predict*.

Comment: Have you considered using "Event"?

Comment: You can use prediction is that sense as well, Michael.

Comment: Or use "forecast".

Comment: You would be predicting the 'phenomenon'

Comment: Or perhaps an ***outcome***

Comment: *Phenomenon* or *outcome* seem closest so far.

Comment: Should be *predictate,* if only it would not clash with *pre-dictate* -- so there seems to be no such single word or expression.

Comment: I suggest **outcome**, too. *"the future of the industry could hinge on the outcome of next month's election"*

Comment: Obviously, we can only predict the **future**. ;)